# Comparing values from two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I was wondering if anyone on here could help me. I have two data frames containing 3 columns: `names`, `gender` `amount` ,for two different years. I would love to be able to compare the rise and fall of  names in each data frame.

Thank you in advance !

edit -

```
d=read.table("names2000.txt",header=FALSE,sep=",") 
colnames(d)=c('name','gender','amount')
```

This provides data for the year `2000`. I then used `do.call(rbind, by(d, list(d$gender), FUN=head,5))` to find the top 5 male and female names which returned

```
   name gender amount
F.1       Linda   F  80412
F.2        Mary   F  65443
F.3    Patricia   F  47920
F.4     Barbara   F  41560
F.5       Susan   F  38019
M.6107    James   M  86139
M.6108   Robert   M  83534
M.6109     John   M  79396
M.6110  Michael   M  65141
M.6111    David   M  60704
```

For the second dataframe I used

```
j=read.table("names2010.txt",header=FALSE,sep=",") 
    colnames(j)=c('name','gender','amount')
```

This returns data for the year '2010' I tried to use `do.call(rbind, by(d, list(d$gender), FUN=head,5))` again to find the top 5 names for male and females this year but I get the error message

```
> "Error in tapply(seq_len(33983L), list(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> 1L,  :    arguments must have same length"
```

I would like to compare for example whether the top 10 name values from the 2000 dataframe rose or fell when compared to the 2010 data farme. Is there a way of working out which amounts for names increased the most between the two years?

Comment: Please post a little sample of your data, and any attempts you've made so far. [Please read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have edited the above to include a little sample of my data. It returns tables of the two data frames, each listing the names of babies born in that year in descending order of amount for females and then for males. Sorry I don't have much else. I really have no idea where to go from here :(

Comment: Your question is now on hold, so it can't receive any answers. Read your question thinking you're someone else and ask yourself: "Can I help this guy? Is there enough information?" Please read: [Help center: How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/How-to-ask). Edit your question and add a data sample (it doesn't need to be big, but it be enough to reproduce the problem), so it can be voted to be reopened. Here we are all happy to help, but we need good info to start with

Comment: Thanks Barranka, I appreciate your response. This is the first question I have ever posted on here, so I apologize for the lack of information contained in it - even now I am still not sure if there is enough there as you may see in the edit that I encountered an error when trying to produce a sample of what I have so far.

Comment: Ok, a good data sample... so now you want to get the top names for each year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two pseudo data frames. It would be great if you can provide full data sets from next time. Here, I combined two data fames, subset top 5 names by year and gender, and calculated gain (increase/decrease) in the end.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(
        names = c("Ana", "Beth", "Caroline", "Diana", "Ellen",
                  "Felicity", "Grace", "Happy", "Irine", "Jasmin",
                  "Andrew", "Bob", "Cabal", "Dan", "Edward",
                  "Fred", "Greg", "Hugh", "Illia", "Jacob"),
        gender = rep(c("F", "M"), each = 10),
        frequency = sample.int(1e6, 20, replace = TRUE),
        year = 2000,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


df2 <- data.frame(
        names = c("Ana", "Beth", "Caroline", "Diana", "Ellen",
                  "Felicity", "Grace", "Happy", "Irine", "Jasmin",
                  "Andrew", "Bob", "Cabal", "Dan", "Edward",
                  "Fred", "Greg", "Hugh", "Illia", "Jacob"),
        gender = rep(c("F", "M"), each = 10),
        frequency = sample.int(1e6, 20, replace = TRUE),
        year = 2010,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

foo <- rbind(df1,df2)%>%
       arrange(year, gender, desc(frequency)) %>% # Sort your data by the three columns
       group_by(year, gender) %>%
       filter(row_number() < 6) %>% # pick up the top 5 names by year and gender
       ungroup() %>%
       group_by(names) %>%
       mutate(gain = frequency - lag(frequency)) %>% # calculate increase/decrease 
       ungroup() %>%
       filter(year == 2010) # select top 5 names from 2010, NA means the name was not in top 5 in 2000.
```

If gain is NA, that means the names were not in the top 5 in 2000. If gain is positive,
the names are in top 5 in both 2000 and 2010 and getting popular. If gain is negative,
the names are in top 5 in the years, but getting less popular. Since I used `sample.int`,
your results will be different.

```
#      names gender year frequency    gain
#1       Ana      F 2010    934706      NA
#2     Irine      F 2010    869691  240576
#3  Caroline      F 2010    651674      NA
#4  Felicity      F 2010    386115 -512275
#5     Happy      F 2010    382388 -278410
#6    Edward      M 2010    827374   57532
#7      Greg      M 2010    794240   76621
#8     Illia      M 2010    723711      NA
#9      Fred      M 2010    668467      NA
#10      Bob      M 2010    599566      NA
```

Comment: I am receiving the error "Error: incorrect size (1), expecting :44284"

Comment: @Frankj77 I tested the code again with my machine, and it is working. One thing you can do is to tease apart the code. You can add up each line and see if R is happy or not. For example, you can run `rbind(df1,df2) %>% arrange(year, gender, desc(frequency))` and see what R returns. If you see a data frame, you want to add another line and see if R is happy or not. By the way, I am using dplyr 0.3.

Comment: It works perfectly with your sample data frames. I think mine must be too big as I get the error "incorrect size (1), expecting :44284" when I run even the first two lines of the code. Is there a way of assigning memory space to a data frame, maybe this would fix the problem?

Comment: @Frankj77 How large are your data? One more thing. If you just run `rbind(df1,df2)`, do you see the error message?

Comment: No error message for rbind(df1,df2), this runs absolutely fine. I have 2 data frames each of about 20,000 observations. I really appreciate your help so far and as I said it works perfectly for your data set..

Comment: @Frankj77 20,000 isn't that big number. If you can tell me where one can get the data, I am happy to try with the data sets.

Comment: Hmm the data is contained within txt files - I am not sure if they are available online. I am just wondering why it is telling me "Error: incorrect size (1), expecting :44284". I'm sure your code would work if I could figure that error out :)

Comment: @Frankj77 All right. I guess this is all I could do for you now. I am not good at interpreting error messages, but it seems that R is probably expecting 44284 rows?